# Ubuntu DVR - what are the options?

Tags: server, camera

According to my research, the best solution to use ubuntu server as a DVR system would be ZoneMinder. is there any alternatives to zoneminder out there?
I'm not really happy it only has a web interface to control/view my cameras. And it doesn't have an option to record video stream non-stop. Am I missing something in its configuration?
And the thing I really disappointed, I cant find a way to control my PTZ camera with it.
what do manufacturers sell along with their standalone linux powered dvr systems?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned the best solution is Zoneminder.

If you are using the 11.10 version of Ubuntu the 1.24.4 version of Zoneminder is there. along with the mythzoneminder to give a friendlier way to watch the videos.

For specific stuff about zoneminder and how it handles the devices I suggest:

**Support Page** - http://www.zoneminder.com/support

**Forum** - http://www.zoneminder.com/forums/